# Webpack with Angular2 doesn't follow dynamic links

Tags: angular, webpack

**The Context**

I want to be able to write a reusable Angular2 component that displays a custom image and can be used by multiple other components. I want the image to be displayed to be able to be customizable, passed through a variable which it uses in the template. But when building with Webpack, Webpack tries to follow the link in the template when packaging files together, and can't find `{{ variableName }}`.

**The Code**

In my Angular2 template:

```
<img src='{{ imgToShow }}' />
```

In my Webpack Config:

```
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
    loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
  },
```

When trying to build, Webpack gives the following error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '{{ imageToShow }}'
```

I already tried packaging all the images by force:

In Webpack config:

```
entry: {
  'img': './app/img.js',
  'app': './app/app.js'
}
```

In **app/img.js**:

```
function requireAll(r) { r.keys().forEach(r); }
requireAll(require.context('./assets/img/', true, /(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif)$/));
```

But it still doesn't work. Webpack still tries to load the file, and even if I remove the `png` and `jpg` matchers from the loader in my config, Angular2 still can't process the file at runtime.

How can I dynamically display different images in Angular2 with Webpack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<img [src]=' imgToShow ' />
```

Now imgToShow can be changed dynamically.

Comment: That works. But now how do I get the compiled filename? Webpack is adding the hash value to the filename for cache busting.

Comment: you should copy all images to dist with webpack copy plugin. when you require any file with webpack like image and using chunks it will rename the image file name and it will not work any more. [read about this plugin here how it works](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin)